# Using an object for database connections

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to OOP having this code and am having a problem creating a database connection, what could be the problem? Strangely am not getting any errors yet i cannot make any MYSQL INSERTS or SELECTS from the database because the connections have not been made

```
    //include the file that contains variables necessary for database connection
require_once 'configurations.php';

//This is the class that will be used for the MySQL Database transactions
class MySQLDatabase
{
    private $database_connection;

    //constructor class
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    public function open_connection()
    {
        $this->database_connection = mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        if (!$this->database_connection)
        {
            //if the connection fails, return the following message and indicate the error
            die("Could not connect to the MYSQL Database due to: " . mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            //if the connection is made to MYSQL database, then select the database being used 
            $database_selection = mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME, $this->database_connection);

            //if the database to be used cannot be selected, return this error
            if (!$database_selection)
            {
                die ("Could not select the database due to: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }//end of function open database
}//end of class MySQLDatabase

$database_transactions = new MySQLDatabase();
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What are you trying that tells you it's not working?

Comment: because there is no database connection, when trying to do an INSERT to the database

Comment: Why not just use one of the pre-built database objects such as mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things I would consider...

- You write `function __construct()`
  but all the other methods and
  properties are either `public` or
  `private` - use `public function
  __construct()`
- Why is the method `open_connection()`
  public? Should it    be called from
  "outside"? Do you want    someone
  to execute this method    directly
  from an object? Think about making it `private function open_connection()` -> http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
- Why use `die()` in OOP? Do you really
  want to output the error message to
  the user? It isn't secure to do that.
  It's better to throw an `Exception` and work with `try{}` and `catch{}` to handle an error -> http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Are you really sure you're getting no error messages at all? Show use your `query` method... Your code should be fine so far (at least you should get an error on screen with `die()` if something is not correct).